# Sequence diagrams alternative and loop creation

Tags: sequence-diagram, uml-designer

I am building a model in the UML Designer plugin and I want to create a sequence diagram that contains a alternative element(if-else) and a loop(for) for the for sequence of messages and calls. But I cannot find these element in the palette to create them. Although, in the documentation they are mentioned as possible to be created.

See my annotates screenshot of my sequence diagram and palette in UML Designer.
[image]

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No combined fragments are not implemented in UML Designer. It should be possible in a future version this year around July.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!